# How can I set the property value to 0 if the referenced model is NULL?

Tags: c#

I'm calculating the value for `WageCost` in `ScheduleWeek` from `ScheduleDays` like this (the property name is the same for wage cost in a day and in a week):

```
public double WageCost => ScheduleDays.Sum(w => w.WageCost);
```

But if `ScheduleDays` is `null`, I get an exception. How can I set the value of `WageCost` to 0 if no `ScheduleDays` exist?

Comment: `ScheduleDays?.Sum(w => w.WageCost) ?? 0;`

Comment: Write a check for null. SeM gave you the new null-conditional opeartor wich isa convencience feature that was added with C# 6 or so. But a good old `if(ScheduleDays == null) WageCost = 0;` would also work.

Comment: @Christopher If I remember correctly, expression bodied properties was added in c#6. So I assumed he is using >=c#6.

Comment: @SeM: It is a solid asumption that anyone has access to those right now. I was just mentioning it for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?`(null-conditional) and `??`(null-coalescing) operators for that:

```
public double WageCost => ScheduleDays?.Sum(w => w.WageCost) ?? 0;
```

References: **[?? Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)** , **[?. and ?[] null-conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)**

Comment: Thanks! Antoine V has almost the same answer, and answered one minute before you did, but I'm accepting yours because of the reference links and because Antoine has more rep than you. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Double verification

`?` for `w?.WageCost` : avoid `NullException`

`??` for `ScheduleDays` : if `null`, takes `0` as value

```
public double WageCost => ScheduleDays?.Sum(w => w?.WageCost) ?? 0;
```